# AWS S3 retrieval network cost optimisation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 buckets containing too many small files size less than 10kb.  They are about 20 million files per month.
I will have too many retrieval requests per month (~50 million).
I'm looking for ways to optimise S3 network cost.

- One way is to keep it in the hot storage within the application (either cache or a file system) and treat S3 as a warm storage.

Using a cold storage (Glacier) is not an option as our users need to access these documents synchronously using our APIs.

I'm wondering if there's an optimisation option in S3 that could be employed here?

My understanding is even if I retrieve one file worth 10kb, the network charges would be only applicable for 10kb correct? Or is it in chunks of different sizes? So that there's a chance of under-fetching?

Comment: You can build a cache layer on top of s3 for small files only.